# Avoiding cross-domain Check and Other Browser Security Checks

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dynamics-crm-2011

We're developing a Dynamics CRM 2011 product that has a button in the ribbon that calls an external API. Currently, for this button to work, the following settings need to be changed in the browser (IE):

[image]

We would like to avoid this, because many of the target customers for this product are very security conscious. Is there a way to write the code so that it will not require these permissions to be changed, but still be able to communicate with the external API? The code running when the button is pressed in CRM is HTML and Javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use JSONP, which bypasses the cross-domain restriction, assuming that this API supports it.

Comment: As for the ActiveX portion of your question, there is no way to bypass that programatically, nor should there be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you in control of the API? If so, look into CORS. With CORS, all you do is basically add a few extra headers to your request response. If you use an AJAX library (like jQuerys $.ajax), you should be able to continue writing code as is. If not, a good article on how to implement cors in Javascript can be found here: http://eriwen.com/javascript/how-to-cors/

To enable cors, read up on http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: Thanks Peeter, that's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about this CRM, but other than JSONP, your best bet is to have a server side script act as a proxy.

So, you would create a script within the same domain as the user interface code.  That script will then use a server side language (such as PHP) to perform the request to the cross domain script on your behalf.  The server side connection has no restriction on which domain it can access, and all the browser knows is that it is sending a request to a page within the calling domain, which is presumably safe.

How you will do this depends on the exact language of choice, but in general you would just need to send the remote API URL as well as any arguments needed to your server side script, which then rebuilds the request to that URL and passes the result back to the client.

Comment: Thanks Telgin, we're looking at CORS and a proxy, and there are differing opinions on our team for either one.